# Would setting group file permissions affect site security?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, security, permissions

I am running an Apache2 (web) server on a Ubuntu (LTS 14.04) server. I would like to be able to edit files on the webserver, however, I don't want it to be vulnerable to the public.

I have a Linux group, called "webusers", and I added the user, that I usually login to SSH with, to that group. I want that group to be able to edit, delete, and view files (using FTP via openSSH, and "ls" "nano" commands). I would also like to move away from using "sudo" in front of every command that I run that plays with the web files. However, most of the online stuff says to make all the files on your webserver 664 (which makes the files not editable by the group). Would changing the group permissions of the files, so it would look like 674, make the web site vulnerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the `webusers` group is well maintained there are not immediate security concerns caused by this change.

I suggest that you also `chmod g+ws` the directory so that file additions  will automatically be associated with the same group.